# How to use Elastic Transcoder in JAVA?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, liferay, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm working a JAVA web project and upload media on S3 with liferay as backend. Now I want to transcode those videos with Elastic Transcoder and then stream them. I want to create a script that helps me process the videos from my project automatically rather than going to Elastic Transcoder console and then making a job every now or then.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed on this?

Also i was trying to add a prefix on the output file of Elastic Transcoder .. but when I Add Output Key it creates a directory instead of adding a prefix to the file.

I want something like **prefix-file-name.[media format]**

Can anyone help regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you would have your process create a job for the media file after the S3 uploads is complete:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-job.html

You should have a pre-defined pipeline you're using to create the job. With regards to the output key/prefix, you should specify the prefix/"directory" as the output prefix, with all other output paths as relative to the output prefix you specify.

An example of setting output prefix/paths can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-job.html#create-job-request-outputs

Comment: Thanks Brandon i followed those docs already and have created the code. Now everything working the way i needed :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! When time permits, would you mind accepting my answer if you found it useful? Thanks!